# Flask-RESTful custom routes for each HTTP method

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I have simple Resource class which defines some API methods:

```
class RoomAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):
        # some code

    def post(self):
        # some code

    def put(self):
        # some code
```

Then I define my routes like this:

```
api.add_resource(RoomAPI,'/api/rooms/')
```

So, my question is: how can I make different routes for each HTTP methos using only one Resource class?

I want to get such API:

```
GET /api/rooms/get/
POST /api/rooms/create/
PUT /api/rooms/update/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is, you shouldn't. That's not RESTful at all.

However, if you really want to, I think you could do it like so:

```
api.add_resource(RoomAPI,'/api/rooms/get', methods=['GET'])
api.add_resource(RoomAPI,'/api/rooms/create', methods=['PUT'])
api.add_resource(RoomAPI,'/api/rooms/update', methods=['POST'])
```

Since the unused `**kwargs` from add_resource get passed to  `add_url_rule()`.